# H5 page in IE browser display problems

Tags: html

H5 page in IE browser display, at the edge of the page will display gray box.How to get rid of the black border at the edge of the page？

[image: h5 page in ie browser display problems]

Comment: can you show a link to the page or a full screenshot?

Comment: a full screenshot

Comment: Do you mean HTML5 or actually the `h5` tag?

Comment: I mean the H5 page is in IE

Comment: @cdonts he meant HTML5. It's commonly called "H5" in China.

Comment: @naiquanxiao please show us the full screenshot then. The small part of image like above can't help us identify the problem.

Comment: Yeah,I'm a Chinese

Comment: Ok  Wait a moment!

Comment: @naiquanxiao some codes showing what you've tried might help too https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You can see my answer.@YongQuan